# Badge Disciplined

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through all of the badges here in stackexchange and came across this **Badge** named **Disciplined** which is **Deleting own post with score of 3 or higher**.

And post is question or an answer? Why to delete a post of 3 or higher score, it would/should be a meaningful post that it secured a score of 3 or higher than what is necessity/reason for deleting?

Just for the sake of a Badge one should delete?

Answer (score 10):

Just because an Answer is upvoted, doesn't mean it's necessarily right. Just because a question is upvoted, doesn't mean it's a [good question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

I guess Disciplined refers to removing an upvoted post because it's simply wrong or bad for the benefit of the community. But that's the key word: community.

Don't delete questions or answers for the sake of a coloured cloud with a number next to it, what if said question or answer helped someone further into the future? Delete it to make this repository as accurate and helpful as possible.

My opinion anyway!